# web 2.0 sucks huge floppy disks?

Tags: html, css, web

I was able to create a web site 10 years ago with Microsoft Frontpage without learning anything, today with a copy of Adobe Dreamweaver CS6, I can't even figure out a way to change the font size of a simple text. CSS is the thing, so I went through the CSS tutorials in w3 and I get it now. It's a good idea, but It is also a good idea to kill creativity, ie all sites like similar, see screenshot below. It sucks floppy disks.

[image]

My questions will be:

1. Does web 2.0 really kill creativity?
2. Is there a "modern" web design application that I don't need to go into these CSS thing?
3. Is there a way to create a circular navigation menu like this using css? I want to have this menu in the middle of the page, and with a button on the corner to activate it.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: my question is, if you designed this menu using some graphics tool like photoshop. then can't you directly generate svg from it ?

Comment: Circle navigation: http://callmenick.com/_development/css-circle-menu/

Comment: Originally its from https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/building-a-circular-navigation-with-svg/ , of course, correct me if im wrong. Web 2.0 - is it still this era? It sounds a little old. And for modern web desing, maybe Indesign. Althougt I prefer gvim:)

Comment: ..... even though I *could* fumble my way through rewiring my home... I'd rather trust an electrician to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No it doesn't
2. You don't have to use CSS. You can use inline styles,
   but it won't be right. Using the CSS is a good coding practice and
   you just need to learn it better.
3. Yes. If you google it, you'll find several links. Here is just some examples:

https://css-tricks.com/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-clip-paths/

http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-circle-menu-with-css3-transitions-transforms/